# Check if JavaScript variable is undefined / false in a function

Tags: javascript

What's the best way to check in a function if a passed argument is undefined?

The return value should be:

- If v is undefined, return false
- If v is defined, return true if v is true, otherwise false

```
function isVariableFalse(v) {
    if (typeof v !== 'undefined') {     
        return false;
    }
    return v ? true: false;
}
```

This issue is that when passing an undefined variable, I already get an error.

E.g.

```
isVariableFalse(someUndefinedVariable)
```

Raises this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError

Comment: Your condition 'If v is defined, return true if v is true, otherwise false' makes it sounds like you just want `v === true;`

Comment: Perhaps you want [default parameters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters)

Comment: That function [should not throw that error](https://jsfiddle.net/1toy9fm5/) when you pass `undefined` to it.

Comment: @Ivar but the error is thrown: Try calling isVariableFalse(some_undefined_variable);

Comment: You cannot use variables that have not been declared unless you are using try/catch: `try{isVariableFalse(some_undefined_variable);} catch() {console.log('ex'}`. But why would you even be dealing with such variables in the first place?

Comment: @str Because the user may declare or not certain variables in a script. So I need to check if the variable is declared and false. Like if (disableMenu === true) { disableMenu() }

Comment: @smolo You should probably use an object instead `const conf = {}; if (conf.disableMenu) { disableMenu() }`.

Comment: @smolo It is possible to use `typeof some_undefined_variable !== 'undefined'`, but you cannot put it inside of a function, because it will break when trying to call that function if it can't find that variable. However allowing users to define their own variables is rarely a good idea and [can potentially be dangerous](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting), so I am curious to know the context.

Comment: This is used for nuBuilder (www.nubuilder.com). So my idea is that users can disable functionality by declaring some (known) variables and settings them to false or true.
On seconds thought, I could simply declare / initialize them with a default value and the user could override them if necessary. That would be the way to go I guess.

Answer (score 0):

You have truthy and falsy notion in JavaScript.

"" is falsy and "something" is truthy.
0 is falsy and 5 is truthy.

So you can use the double negation notation if you don't want to deal with too much cases:

```js
let my_var = <some_value>;

if(!!my_var) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: Using double negation inside an if-statement makes no sense. Expressions in an if-statement are already used in a boolean context.

Comment: It was for giving an example sorry for my lack of imagination ^_^

Comment: This doesn't work. I get a ReferenceError: v is not defined
And this kind of error is execatly that I want to catch

Comment: Can we see more code, maybe the problem is elsewhere?

Comment: @MetallimaX Check out https://jsfiddle.net/Smolo/2648pbn7/ and open the developer console

Comment: You at least have to declare your variable: `let some_undefined_variable;`

Answer (score 0):

The reason your function is giving you an error, is because when passing arguments to a function, javascript does not pass the variable but rather unpacks the variable and sends its value (or a reference to its value). So when you give an undefined var as an argument, there is nothing to unpack and so an error occurs. Luckily there are simple ways of checking if a var exists already, without building your own function, such as

```js
if (v) { }

if (v !== undefined) { }
```

etc.

**Edit** Passing as a string.

```js
function isVariableFalse(v) {
  return !!this[v] // Or you can write your own checks. Access the variable with this[v]
}
```

*Note* that this won't work for variables local to the calling function, since they only exist there. Eg. (eval wouldn't work either)

```js
function a() {
  let c = 5;
  console.log(isVariableFalse('c')) // Will output 'false'
}
```

Comment: Sure, I can check if v is undefined and then if it is true or false but actually  for the sake of refactoring I wanted to have a function since I need to check more than one variable.

Comment: Sure, but that's my point. It won't work passing it to a function. But you can use `if (v)` or just `!!v` wherever you would use the function and it should work.

Comment: Check out jsfiddle.net/Smolo/2648pbn7 and open the developer console

Comment: Yes. I understand your error. Did you read my answer?? You can't pass undefined variables into functions. That is why you get an error. You have to check them right then and there. And as I have said before, you can check them simply with `if (v)` or `!!v`

Comment: Yes, I understand now that I can't. This was actually my question.. I know that I can check them outside a function. But I could probably pass them as string like 
isVariableFalse('somevariable') and use eval() inside the function.

Comment: Yes you could pass them as a string if you wanted. I'll edit the question to show how you could do it without eval though.

Comment: That would be great! Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I edited the answer. Note the limitation, the function can only check global variables. If you passed a context as an argument as well, you could check variables of objects, but still not local function vars.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting Reference Error is beacuse you haven't declared SomeUndefinedVariable Which u passed in IsVariableFalse function.So you must declare a variable before passing into IsVariableFalse function like below
`var SomeUndefinedVariable;`  `//Which by default is undefined`